# What's the best way to write classes that are only different in some attributes?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

*(revised example)*

```java
// A.java
public class A {
    private static final String name = "A";

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("name is " + name);
    }

    public void doSomethingELse() {
        // do something
    }
}

// B.java
public class B {
    private static final String name = "B";

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("name is " + name);
    }

    public void doSomethingELse() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Like the example above, I have 2 similar classes that are only different in the `name` attribute.

I want to create an interface or an abstract class, in order to reuse the logic of `print` function. What is the recommended way of doing that?

Comment: @Mat The other methods which I omitted might have other functions that are different.

Comment: I think it is a quite common situation where you have many similar classes, and you want to reuse the logic for a long long function. However, the fucntion uses a attribute that are present in all the classes but the values are different.

Comment: You seem to be focusing on the wrong thing. Your name attribute is an instance field, and so it is a property of the object, not the class, and you wouldn't create multiple classes if this were the key thing that changes. In this situation, it's the differing behaviors that likely matter more, the information that you *don't* show us.

Comment: I think that this question could be improved by making both the problem and the code more concrete, showing more of a realistic and real-life code example. Else we could be barking up an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) tree.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Tried my best to make the question clearer.

Comment: I'm sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear about what I meant by "more concrete". This would be posting code that is much closer to your current production code, code that shows some purpose, as well as telling more detail about how this question and issue fits into your current project. But if QBrute's answer fully answers your question, then feel free to ignore this suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You already have an `abstract` class that you can use as parent to `A` and `B`. Parent classes contain fields and methods that are common to all child classes.

You can use `abstract` methods in the parent class to denote methods that need to be implemented by the children, i.e. behvavior that differs from child to child.

So I'd suggest the following:

```
public abstract class I {
    /**
     * Common attribute for all children.
     */
    private final String name;

    protected I(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "It is " + name;
    }

    /**
     * Needs to be explicitly implemented by all children.
     */ 
    public abstract void someMethod1();

    /**
     * Needs to be explicitly implemented by all children.
     */
    public abstract void someMethod2();
}

public class A extends I {
    public A() {
        super("A");
    }

    @Override
    public void someMethod1() {
        // specific implementation for A
    }

    @Override
    public void someMethod2() {
        // specific implementation for A
    }
}

public class B extends I {
    public B() {
        super("B");
    }

    @Override
    public void someMethod1() {
        // specific implementation for B
    }

    @Override
    public void someMethod2() {
        // specific implementation for B
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel that this way reduces readability. When somebody looks at a child class and see a `super("A")`, they mighy not understand what the value "A" actually is.

Comment: @Noah: I see nothing unclear about QBrute's code nor is its readability compromised in any way (1+).

Comment: @Noah in general this is how a solution to your problem is usually achieved. If you feel that literals like `"A"` are not expressive enough, you can always extract them into constants like `private static final String NAME_OF_A = "A"` and then use it in your constructor like `super(NAME_OF_A)`